# How does it express that atomic velocities have no preferred direction?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, symmetry

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is a derivation of equation of internal energy of an ideal gas from Heat and Thermodynamics-Zemansky.
I am not sure if attaching images like i have would cause inconvenience. I had to type the whole thing if i had to ask my question.
Can anyone explain how the equation tells us that atomic velocities have no preferred directions?

Comment: *I am not sure if attaching images like i have would cause inconvenience.* Images of text and math are not appropriate here because they can’t be searched and can’t be read by visually-impaired members. You are expected to type the text and use MathJax for the math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question let me write how the equation would look like if the velocity were anisotropic:
$$
d^3N_{w,\theta,\phi} = dN_w g(\theta,\phi) d\Omega.
$$
In words: the number of particles having velocity vector between $\vec{w}$ and $\vec{w} + d\vec{w}$ is:

- proportional to the number of particles having velocity modulus between $w$ and $w+dw$,
- proportional to the solid angle element $d\Omega$,
- dependent by a (normalized) directional factor $g(\theta,\phi)$ which changes with the velocity direction.

When the system is isotropic, then $g(\theta,\phi) = 1/4\pi$, which is independent on $\theta,\phi$. The constant $1/4\pi$ is chosen because $g(\theta,\phi)$ must be normalized.

Hope this helped!